# Allow current user to navigate only his own posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I am using a custom plugin to add previous and next links in the "admin edit post" page. This so that the author can easily skip from his own posts (previous to next) without having to leave that page in the backend.

I am however struggling with how I need to get there.
Is the below adjustable to make it display only the current editing user ?

```
function change_apn_post_status( $post_statuses, $post_type ) {
// Add a post status.
// Note: by default these are already in the $post_statuses array: 'draft', 'future', 'pending', 'private', 'publish'
$post_statuses[] = 'trash';

// Remove post status(es).
$post_statuses_to_remove = array( 'draft' ); // Customize here.
if ( 'page' === $post_type ) {
    $post_statuses_to_remove[] = 'pending';
}
foreach ( $post_statuses_to_remove as $remove ) {
    if ( false !== $index = array_search( $remove, $post_statuses ) ) {
        unset( $post_statuses[ $index ] );
    }
}

return array_values( $post_statuses );
}
add_filter( 'c2c_admin_post_navigation_post_statuses', 'change_apn_post_status', 10, 2 );'
```

I thought this was a good starting point but alas I can't get it to work

```
global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();
$author_query = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'author' => $current_user->ID
);
```